# Calculate date diff in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table which has the following columns -

`Id   end_time   status
 12   1407477033 success
 13   1407479820 error
 14   1407479974 error`

I have to find all the id's which have status 'error' and were completed in the last 15 minutes. I am using ruby to interact with the database, so my query becomes ( the table name is q_lists ). To find the time difference I am using [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms189794.aspx) -

```
date = QList.find_by_sql("select end_time from q_lists where id = #{a.id}")
diff = QList.find_by_sql("select DATEDIFF(minute, FROM_UNIXTIME(date), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
```

Note : a is the loop variable,I am iterating for each row.
I am getting the following error -

```
ERROR 1582 (42000): Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'
```

How can I resolve this. Also can I write the query in a way all the id's are stored in an array using just one sql statement (without loop iterations).

**EDIT**
TIMESTAMPDIFF solves the problem. Sorry for squishing two questions in one, but can someone point the correct way of getting all id's in just one go without using loops.

Comment: where are you running this line in c# ?
select DATEDIFF(minute, FROM_UNIXTIME(date), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's DATEDIFF is not the same as Microsoft's. It does not include the first parameter, and will only return the number of days between two dates. You want [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)